# Help with Wordpress function inside a shortcode

Tags: php, functions, shortcode

I'm trying to spice up a theme of mine with some shortcode buttons but I'm having quite a bit of trouble when trying to call the author's name within the button itself. I tried simply including

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[button type="square" color="black" size="small"] Posted by <?php the_author(); ?> [/button]'); ?>
```

in the theme where I want the button with the author's name to appear, but it just gives a button that says 'Posted by '. I'm not the most experienced coder, but I know a little bit of everything from tinkering with various themes over the years. All help is appreciated, thanks in advance!
-Matt

Comment: I'm not that familiar (yet) with the internal functions of WordPress, but is [`do_shortcode`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode) supposed to be able to accept PHP tags `<?php ... ?>` inside of a string?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're using a php tag within a php tag. I'd try something more like this...

```
<?php 
    echo do_shortcode('[button type="square" color="black" size="small"] Posted by '.get_the_author().' [/button]');
?>
```

or something like this...

```
<?php 
    $shortcode = '[button type="square" color="black" size="small"] Posted by '.get_the_author().' [/button]';
    echo "do_shortcode('$shortcode')";
?>
```

Comment: replace `the_author()` with `get_the_author()` in your answer, because you are using it in a concatenated string.

Comment: Ah, good catch, fixed!